# How to get a list of supported languages

Tags: next.js, i18next

I need to do a a Select of languages in my nextjs application, but I wanted it to be dynamic, have any way to get a list of i18n used languages?

For example:

```
const languages = i18n.languages
```

I tried to get it from the next-i18next.config file, but i want a i18n lib way...